# What is the difference between a "set rule" and a "fixed rule"?

Tags: american-english

> There isn't a **set rule** for English pronunciation.
>
> There isn't a **fixed rule** for English pronunciation.

Do these two phrases have the same meaning or are their meanings different?

Comment: They're equivalent, but [***a fixed rule*** is far more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+set+rule+for%2Ca+fixed+rule+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20set%20rule%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20fixed%20rule%20for%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20set%20rule%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20fixed%20rule%20for%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2):

These sentences have the same meaning.

**Set** is used as "Set in place", meaning there isn't an established rule that is law or commonly accepted.

**Fixed** is used as "Fixed in place", meaning the same thing.

In this instance, **set** and **fixed** are synonyms.